# ajax script for change background not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am facing a problem with ajax script. I am using the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#savecolor').click(function(){     
          var myVar = 'data='+$('#color').val();
          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "addcolor.php",
            data: myVar,
            success: function(msg){
            //alert(myVar);
            $('#message').html('Background color has been changed successfully.');
            $(window.parent.document).find('#set').css('background', msg);
             //$('#set').css('background', msg);
              // window.parent.location.reload(); 

               }
              });
             });
</script>
```

This code is working fine but in IE this is not working, i am using jquery-1.7

any one help me.

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?531678-window-parent-content-document-doesn-t-work-in-IE&s=2f04b84bb723a9cbaca75b4ff33aa3c1&p=3722571&viewfull=1#post3722571

Comment: are you doing this action in a `popup` window or iframe?

Comment: try background-color instead of background into your code.

Comment: yes @MuthuKumaran i am using this code in popup.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the solution is to replace `$(window.parent.document).find('#set').css('background', msg);` with `$('#set').css('background', msg);`

Use `alert(msg)` to see what the function is returning in IE

Comment: This code is run on ifram and used to change the background of parent window

Comment: Hi guys, i was got solution myself there was jquery conflict problem.